# How to run "source" command from python?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, ros2

I need to set up the ROS2 Galactic environment by sourcing the following file through python: -

"source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash"

If I write the above line in terminal it will be sourced but I need to do this from python script.

I tried: -

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash", shell=True)
```

and

```
import os
os.system('source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash')
```

But none of them is sourcing the enviornment. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.10.

Answer (score 0):

This will not impact your Python runtime environment. subprocess starts a shell wherein it runs your script (setup.bash) and then terminates.

Consider this:

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.run('export FOO=1', shell=True)
print(os.environ['FOO'])
```

This tries to set an environment variable in the sub-shell. That actually works but when run() returns, the shell no longer exists. Thus, when we try to access the environment variable we get KeyError